# Issue removing two patterns (string and numbers) using regex in R

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to remove two patterns using `str_replace` in R.

The patterns that I would like to remove are `\\d+_` and `Baskets`

I first tried:

```
> library(stringr)

> variables <- c("1_SmallBaskets", "2_Medium", "3_High")

> str_replace(variables, "Baskets|\\d+_", "")

[1] "SmallBaskets" "Medium"       "High"
```

As far as I can make out, as the pattern `\\d+_` comes first this is replaced but then it moves onto the next without replacing the `Baskets`

I then tried making the expression greedy (example below), but this seems to only be checking for the expression `Baskets`

```
> str_replace(variables, "Baskets|\\d+_/g", "")

[1] "1_Small"  "2_Medium" "3_High"
```

I have tested that the syntax `Small|High` works, i.e. replaces Small or High, so I don't understand why when trying to replace a digit and a character the same logic doesn't apply

Comment: Why not use `str_replace_all`? You only replace one occurrence with `str_replace`.

Comment: I guess `/g` is a typo in the second snippet. At some online regex tester (or in JavaScript), you will need `/g` modifier to get multiple matches. In R, you need to use specific function to "emulate" this flag.

Comment: thanks for the comment I wasn't aware of that, I was just using online regex tester as you mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `str_replace`, you only replace *the first occurrence*. With `str_replace_all`, you will replace *all occurrences*, all matches inside one string. See this code:

```
> library(stringr)
> variables <- c("1_SmallBaskets", "2_Medium", "3_High")
> str_replace(variables, "Baskets|\\d+_", "")
[1] "SmallBaskets" "Medium"       "High"        
> str_replace_all(variables, "Baskets|\\d+_", "")
[1] "Small"  "Medium" "High"
```

Also, you can really just leverage the `gsub` here:

```
> gsub("Baskets|\\d+_", "", variables)
[1] "Small"  "Medium" "High"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Out of interest do you know why `str_replace(variables, "Small|High", "")` will replace both Small and High?

Comment: Yes, it will, because there is only one `Small` in `1_SmallBaskets` and only one `High` in `3_High`. These vectors are handled one by one, not as one string.